# Disable forms with JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to display some forms on my view but it doesn't seem to work. 
These are the forms I want to disable.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Start tid:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBox("startTime", Model.Times.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Slut tid:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBox("endTime", Model.Times.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Rast Längd:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBox("breakTime", Model.Times.BreakTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tid jobbad:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBox("workedHours", Model.Times.WorkedHours, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my checkbox:

```
                                <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
                                Ingen tid att rappotera
                            </label>
```

And this is my script:

```
    $('#check').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked') === false){
        $('startTime').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    }
    else {
        $('startTime').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Also tried having the script like this

```
    $('#check').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked') === false){
        $('#startTime').prop("disabled","disabled");   
    }
    else {
        $('#startTime').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

I know the script at it current state would only disable the startTime form, but I am fine with that just want to get it working so I can add the other forms later. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: `.attr(...)` should be `.prop(...)` -> `$(this).prop("checked")` and `$('startTime').prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: @Andreas Tried that already.

Comment: That's not a solution but a best practice ;)

Comment: @Andreas Alright, cool.

Comment: Is the `click` handler called at all? If not, is the `$('#check').click(...)` part wrapped in a `document.ready` handler / or at least **after** the checkbox (preferable right before the closing `<body>` tag)?

Comment: @Andreas I forgot the document.ready....